# Spring Boot MapR sandbox port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mapr

Trying to connect MapR sandbox VM from Spring Boot configuration.

```
 @Bean FsShell fsShell() {
            org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration hadoopconfiguration = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
            hadoopconfiguration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020");
            return new FsShell(hadoopconfiguration);
        }
```

I am using VM. Initially used NAT  and then moved to bridge for VM network configuration. However it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have switched to "Bridged Network" (or host only to have a local network)  *(this is what I do also when I use the MapR Sandbox)* you also need to use a different IP address.

Your MapR node has now its how IP address coming from your network, so:

- connect to your VM and get the IP address (`ifconfig`)
- use this IP address to connect from your boot application

note: the other option is to run your application from the VM (this should work too)